# have an object that is an equation written with sprintf evaluate in R

Tags: r

Say I have written the following object, an equation, `eqn.r`, using the sprintf command in R, that evaluates based on a vector of input, `pizza`:

```
eqn.r<- sprintf("sum((%s - mean(%s,na.rm=T))^2,na.rm=T)",pizza,pizza)
pizza<-c(1:10)
```

When I type `eqn.r` into the R console I get this:

```
"sum((pizza - mean(pizza,na.rm=T))^2,na.rm=T)"
```

I want it to actually evaluate, and print this:

```
> sum((pizza - mean(pizza,na.rm=T))^2,na.rm=T)
[1] 82.5
```

Comment: Use `"pizza", "pizza"` in `sprintf()` then you can evaluate `eval(parse(text = eqn.r))` but this not recommended at all ever anywhere in the history of the world.  Why do you even need a string?  Just use the last line.

Comment: @RichardScriven I'm writing a command that takes as input a dataset, and a variable name within that dataset (in this example pizza), I want to run an this equation on the variable within the dataset, each of whicha re supplied by the user to the particular function. so: f(data,pizza){eqn}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a variable name stored as a string, you can the variable's data from the passed data frame using standard indexing. In general, this is much preferred to generating code with something like `sprintf` or `paste` and then parsing and evaluating that code.

```
f <- function(dat, vname) sum((dat[,vname] - mean(dat[,vname], na.rm=T))^2, na.rm=T)
f(iris, "Sepal.Length")
# [1] 102.1683
```

If you wanted to invoke your function without quotes around the variable name, you could do:

```
f2 <- function(dat, vname) {
  m <- match.call()
  x <- with(eval(m[["dat"]]), eval(m[["vname"]]))
  sum((x - mean(x,na.rm=T))^2,na.rm=T)
}
f2(iris, Sepal.Length)
# [1] 102.1683
```